# centos 7 postgresql not starting

Tags: centos7, postgresql-9.4

I installed Centos 7, 64 bit. Installed postgresql-9.4. 
Initialized postgresql with command

```
/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/postgresql94-setup initdb
```

then used this command to start postgresql

```
systemctl start postgresql-9.4
```

and showed error like this:

```
service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status postgresql-9.4.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

entered command

```
systemctl status postgresql-9.4.service
● postgresql-9.4.service - PostgreSQL 9.4 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.4.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-03-02 18:09:27 CST; 1min 59s ago
  Process: 31266 ExecStart=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -w -t 300 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 31261 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/postgresql94-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 02 18:09:26 localhost.localdomain pg_ctl[31266]: < 2016-03-02 18:09:26.862 CST >LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use
Mar 02 18:09:26 localhost.localdomain pg_ctl[31266]: < 2016-03-02 18:09:26.862 CST >HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on...retry.
Mar 02 18:09:26 localhost.localdomain pg_ctl[31266]: < 2016-03-02 18:09:26.862 CST >LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
Mar 02 18:09:26 localhost.localdomain pg_ctl[31266]: < 2016-03-02 18:09:26.862 CST >HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on...retry.
Mar 02 18:09:26 localhost.localdomain pg_ctl[31266]: < 2016-03-02 18:09:26.862 CST >WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
Mar 02 18:09:26 localhost.localdomain pg_ctl[31266]: < 2016-03-02 18:09:26.862 CST >FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
Mar 02 18:09:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql-9.4.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 02 18:09:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 9.4 database server.
Mar 02 18:09:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit postgresql-9.4.service entered failed state.
Mar 02 18:09:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql-9.4.service failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

**1** - install psmisc package to give a killall on Postgres

*# yum install psmisc*

**2** - Run the kill
*# killall -9 postgres* 

**3** - Start / Stop

*# systemctl stop postgresql- 9.4* 
*# systemctl start postgresql- 9.4*

**4** - to check if the service is in execution,

*# ps -aux | grep postgres*